# Flood and Statistics

Tags: hydrology, precipitation, flooding, dams

A recent flood was due to combined effect of rainfall(precipitation) and reservoir storage. I have daily rainfall data and reservoir storage data. How can I correlate these two to get a statistical model?

Comment: A statistical model of what? How they correlate with each other?

Comment: Sounds like you either want a hydrologic model to 'correlate' the two, or do you mean in terms of describing the joint probability and return period of the rainfall event and reservoir storage?